# Javascript Array and While Loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I am very new to javascript and I am trying to list a certain number of job duties on a resume site (dictated by a user input). For example, I ask the user to input the number of job duties they want to see, and using an array and while loop I've been tasked with displaying that many job duties. However, when I click the button, noting is happening. I am not getting any web console errors at all. Here is what I have so far:

```
<div id="right">
            <p> <b> Byrne Dairy</b><br/>
            QA Lab Technician<br/>
            September 2015 - March 2016<br/><br/><br/>

            <button value="Click" onclick="listDuties()">Click</button> to see my top
                <input type="text" id="byrne_duties" value="0"/> job duties here:<br/><br/><br/>
            <p id="duties"></p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function listDuties() {
            var byrneduties = [     "Gathering product samples from sanitized silo and tank ports on a timely schedule. <br/> ",
                                    "Regularly use of Delta Testing Instruments to measure solids and fat contents of products. ",
                                    "Performing the Gerber Method of testing on samples. ",
                                    "Responsible for using the Standard Plate Count method of developing colonies of bacteria. ",
                                    "Interpreting results of bacterial and coliform growth patterns in products. " ];
            var x = byrneduties[0];
            var text = "";
            while (byrneduties[x]) {
            text += byrneduties[x] + "<br>";
            x++;
            document.getElementById('duties').innerHTML = x;
            }
            }
            </script>


        </div>
```

I was told to try and subtract one from the user input, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help would be great!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var x = 0;` instead of `var x = byrneduties[0];` and `document.getElementById('duties').innerHTML = text` ?

Comment: You need to learn how to debug.  Simply stepping through your code you would realize that x is going to be "Gathering product samples blah blah boring", which you then try to use to index into the array `byrneduties[x]`.  Array indexes are numbers, not text.  Since javascript don't GAF, it just returns undefined. What you're doing right now--STOP.  Go read this https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: Titus, when I do that, no matter what the user input for number of job duties they want to see, it prints all 5. Any thoughts?

Comment: You will first have to get the user's input `var userChoice = parseInt(document.getElementById("byrne_duties").value)` and then change the loop's condition to `while(x < userChoice)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, there're some errors in your code:

- First of all, your while condition is not a boolean (true/false) but a value of a string array
- The var `x` that you use as index in the loop, is initialized with the first element of string array, then incremented (string+1?!) and finally returned back into an html object (p)

Look the following reviewed code, where I made the above little changes:

```js
function listDuties() {
  var byrneduties = ["Gathering product samples from sanitized silo and tank ports on a timely schedule. <br/> ","Regularly use of Delta Testing Instruments to measure solids and fat contents of products. ","Performing the Gerber Method of testing on samples. ","Responsible for using the Standard Plate Count method of developing colonies of bacteria. ","Interpreting results of bacterial and coliform growth patterns in products. " ];
  
  var n = document.getElementById('byrne_duties').value;
  var x = 0;
  var text = "";
  while (x < n) {
    text += byrneduties[x] + "<br>";
    x++;
  }
  document.getElementById('duties').innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<div id="right">
    <p> <b> Byrne Dairy</b><br/>
    QA Lab Technician<br/>
    September 2015 - March 2016<br/><br/><br/>

    <button value="Click" onclick="listDuties()">Click</button> to see my top
        <input type="text" id="byrne_duties" value="0"/> job duties here:<br/><br/><br/>
    <p id="duties"></p>

</div>
```

I hope it was clear, bye.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate the explanation as well.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, bye.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I click the button, noting is happening. I am not
>   getting any web console errors at all.

Your current code is simply going to display only one **duty** since it is over-writing the same **div** again and again. It is not even taking input from the **textbox** into consideration.

try this

```html
<div id="right">
  <p> <b> Byrne Dairy</b><br/> QA Lab Technician<br/> September 2015 - March 2016<br/><br/><br/>

    <button value="Click" onclick="listDuties()">Click</button> to see my top
    <input type="text" id="byrne_duties" value="0" /> job duties here:<br/><br/><br/>
    <p id="duties"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function listDuties() {
        var byrneduties = ["Gathering product samples from sanitized silo and tank ports on a timely schedule. <br/> ",
          "Regularly use of Delta Testing Instruments to measure solids and fat contents of products. ",
          "Performing the Gerber Method of testing on samples. ",
          "Responsible for using the Standard Plate Count method of developing colonies of bacteria. ",
          "Interpreting results of bacterial and coliform growth patterns in products. "
        ];
        var numberOfDuties = Number( document.getElementById( "byrne_duties" ).value );
        if ( !isNaN( numberOfDuties ) && numberOfDuties > 0 )
        {
           document.getElementById('duties').innerHTML = byrneduties.slice(0, numberOfDuties).join("<br>");
        }
      }
    </script>


</div>
```

Comment: @JordanJackson `If` statement is to check if the user has entered a positive number in the `textbox`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

```
var x = byrneduties[0]; // here x is variable which refer to first byrneduties
var text = "";

while (byrneduties[x]) { // here x is index, I think you meant 'i'
        text += byrneduties[x] + "<br>";
        x++;
        document.getElementById('duties').innerHTML = x;
```

No need to loop, just join array

```
 document.getElementById('duties').innerHTML = byrneduties.join('<br/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array with a foreach, like in the following example:

```html
<div id="right">
            <p> <b> Byrne Dairy</b><br/>
            QA Lab Technician<br/>
            September 2015 - March 2016<br/><br/><br/>

            <button value="Click" onclick="listDuties()">Click</button> to see my top
                <input type="text" id="byrne_duties" value="0"/> job duties here:<br/><br/><br/>
            <p id="duties"></p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function listDuties() {
            var byrneduties = [     "Gathering product samples from sanitized silo and tank ports on a timely schedule. <br/> ",
                                    "Regularly use of Delta Testing Instruments to measure solids and fat contents of products. ",
                                    "Performing the Gerber Method of testing on samples. ",
                                    "Responsible for using the Standard Plate Count method of developing colonies of bacteria. ",
                                    "Interpreting results of bacterial and coliform growth patterns in products. " ];
                                    
            var text = "";
            
            byrneduties.forEach( (duty, i)=>{
              if ( (i+1) > document.getElementById('byrne_duties').value ) {
                return;
              }
              text += (i+1) + ") " + duty + "<br/>"
            });
            
            
            document.getElementById('duties').innerHTML = text;
            }
            </script>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function listDuties() {
            var byrneduties = [     "Gathering product samples from sanitized silo and tank ports on a timely schedule. <br/> ",
                                    "Regularly use of Delta Testing Instruments to measure solids and fat contents of products. ",
                                    "Performing the Gerber Method of testing on samples. ",
                                    "Responsible for using the Standard Plate Count method of developing colonies of bacteria. ",
                                    "Interpreting results of bacterial and coliform growth patterns in products. " ];
            var x = 0;
            var text = "";
                  var input =document.getElementById('byrne_duties').value
            while (x<byrneduties.length && x<input) {
            text += byrneduties[x] + "<br>";
            x++;
            document.getElementById('duties').innerHTML = text;
            }
            }
```

```html
<div id="right">
            <p> <b> Byrne Dairy</b><br/>
            QA Lab Technician<br/>
            September 2015 - March 2016<br/><br/><br/>

            <button value="Click" onclick="listDuties()">Click</button> to see my top
                <input type="text" id="byrne_duties" value="0"/> job duties here:<br/><br/><br/>
            <p id="duties"></p>



        </div>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Here is your mistakes.

```
var x = byrneduties[0]; // x is "Gathering product samples from sanitized silo and tank ports on a timely schedule. <br/>"
var text = "";
while (byrneduties[x]) { // byrneduties["Gathering product samples from sanitized silo and tank ports on a timely schedule. <br/>"] returns undefined
    text += byrneduties[x] + "<br>"; 
    x++; // string increment probably returns NaN
    document.getElementById('duties').innerHTML = x; //set inner html to NaN.
}
```

Rewrite it in next way

```
var x = 0;
var text = "";
while (byrneduties[x]) {
    text += byrneduties[x] + '<br/>';
    x++;
}
document.getElementById('duties').innerHTML = text ;
```

Or use [array.join](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

```
var text = byrneduties.join('<br/>');
document.getElementById('duties').innerHTML = text;
```